# Differentiation Problem solving

Tags: derivatives

A certain magical substance that is used to make solid magical spheres costs $\$800$ per cubic foot. The power of a magical sphere depends on its surface area, and a magical sphere can be sold for $\$20$ per square foot of surface area. If you are manufacturing such a sphere, what size should you make them to maximize your profit per sphere?

Hi im really struggling with this one. Can someone please show how to to complete question.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: the formulas for the volume and surface area of a sphere of radius $r$ are:

$$V= (4 \pi/3)r^3, ~~ A=(4 \pi)(r^2)$$

Let $p$ be the profit, then

$$p(r) = 20 \left(4 \pi  r^2\right)-\frac{800}{3} \left(4 \pi  r^3\right) = 80 \pi  r^2-\frac{3200 \pi  r^3}{3}$$

A plot of the profit function shows:

[image]

$p'=160 \pi  r-3200 \pi  r^2 = 0 \implies r = 0, r = \frac{1}{20}$ ($r \ne 0$)

$p'' = 160 \pi -6400 \pi  r \rightarrow p''\left(\frac{1}{20}\right) = -160 \pi \lt 0$

$r = \frac{1}{20}$ ft gives a maximum profit, thus:

$$p\left(\frac{1}{20}\right) = \frac{\pi }{15} = 0.20944$$